# Using history.push() re-renders current component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, use-effect

I have a component that gets a value from current location state and passes it down to child components.

```
interface RequestProcessingLocationState {
  request: RequestType; 
}
function RequestProcessing() { 
    const location = useLocation<RequestProcessingLocationState>();
    return (
     <div>
         <RequestDetails
             processId={location.state.request.processId}
             requestTitle={location.state.request.title}
         />
         <RequestForm request={location.state.request} />
     </div>
    ); 
}
```

One of the child components has a form that calls a REST endpoint and processes the request.

```
function RequestForm ({ request}: RequestFormPropsType): ReactElement {
    ... 
    const history = useHistory();
    useEffect(() => {     
        axiosInstance.get(/request/${request.id}/form) 
        .then((result) => {
             setForm(result.data);       
        }) 
        .catch((error) => {         
            console.log(error);       
     });   }, [request]);

const handleSubmit = ({ formData }: any) => { 
    axiosInstance.put(/request/process/${request.id}, formData)       
    .then(() => { 
        message.success(t("request-success")); 
        history.push("/requests); 
        })       
        .catch((error) => { 
            console.log(error.response); 
        });
};
    return ( ...)
}
```

The problem occurs when the handleSubmit method is called, specifically when the history.push() is executed. For some reason the useEffect() method of RequestForm component is executed once again, and the axios call throws an error because the request has already been processed.

My guess is that when the location is changed, the component is immediately updated because the request in dependency array comes from location state.

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I think because of your `request` dependency, you need not pass the dependency in `useEffect` because it's prop.
use Like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {     
    request && axiosInstance.get(/request/${request.id}/form) 
    .then((result) => {
         setForm(result.data);       
    }) 
    .catch((error) => {         
        console.log(error);
  // remove warning
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
 });   }, []);
```

it just call once when component is mounted

Comment: Compiler is still warning me about missing dependency if I remove it.

Comment: // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps use this one, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the submission of form by default. To prevent this in your submit function `handleSubmit` you have to add `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to affect the behaviour.

Comment: There's not much info given to find a solution, can you share your code in sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a second parameter to the useEffect hook an empty array like that .

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Run! Like go get some data from an API.
  }, []);
```

Comment: I have the second dependency parameter already - it uses the request object as an dependency.